# Get UDID of iOS Simulators programmatically using c#

Tags: c#, ios, dynamic, udid

I am using c# visual studio to automate iOS apps and the simulators UDID gets changed every time, I do not want to manually type the UDID of simulator every-time... I need help where the system automatically gets the UDID of the booted simulator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can launch from C# a system tool [simctl](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/iOS_Simulator_Guide/InteractingwiththeiOSSimulator/InteractingwiththeiOSSimulator.html) , to see manual page, launch in Terminal:

```
xcrun simctl help
```

You can get list of devices in JSON format and find device with state `Booted`:

```
xcrun simctl list --json devices available

<...>
{
        "dataPath" : "\/Users\/admin\/Library\/Developer\/CoreSimulator\/Devices\/2BE68BC5-02C0-4B1C-92EC-E80CCE713144\/data",
        "logPath" : "\/Users\/admin\/Library\/Logs\/CoreSimulator\/2BE68BC5-02C0-4B1C-92EC-E80CCE713144",
        "udid" : "2BE68BC5-02C0-4B1C-92EC-E80CCE713144",
        "isAvailable" : true,
        "deviceTypeIdentifier" : "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-12-Pro-Max",
        "state" : "Booted",
        "name" : "iPhone 12 Pro Max"
      },
<....>
```

Or in less convenient for C# way:

```
xcrun simctl list | grep Booted
```

You can find path to xcrun with:

```
which xcrun
```

Comment: Do you know how to deserialise the above json file?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/how-to?pivots=dotnet-8-0